# Can't use .getServletContext().getRealPath() to get the real file path under Tomcat 7

Tags: servlets

I am trying to create a visit counter for Tomcat webapp  using Servlet 3.0. I want to load the InitServlet into memory on the Tomcat startup. Following is my java code:

```
package com.yehang;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

 @WebServlet(name="InitServlet",urlPatterns={"/InitServlet"},loadOnStartup=1)
public class InitServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public InitServlet() {
        super();
       }

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

    // read the nums from the recoder.txt
    // 1. get the file path
    String filePath = this.getServletContext().getRealPath("recorder.txt");
    //System.out.println(filePath);
    try {
        // 2. open a filereader
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);
        // 3. put the fileReader into a bufferedreader
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        // 4 read the nums from the bufferedreader
        String nums = bufferedReader.readLine();
        bufferedReader.close();
        System.out.println(nums);
        // put nums into context
        this.getServletContext().setAttribute("nums", nums);
        // cloese the stream(important)
        fileReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void destroy() {
    // write the nums to the recoder.txt
    // 1. get the file path
    String filePath = this.getServletContext().getRealPath("recorder.txt");
    try {
        // 2. open a fileWriter
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filePath);
        // 3. put the fileWriter into a bufferedWriter
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        // 4. get the nums from the context
        String nums = (String) this.getServletContext()
                .getAttribute("nums");
        // write into the file
        bufferedWriter.write(nums);
        // close the stream(important)
        bufferedWriter.close();
        fileWriter.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
    }
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset = utf-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    this.doGet(request, response);
}
}
```

My design is load this class into the memory and invoke the init() method on Tomcat startup. The init() method will read a number from recorder.txt under WebContent, and put the number into context. When Tomcat stop, it will invoke the destroy() method to get the new number from the context and write back to the recorder.txt file. The number in the .txt file will be updated.

However when I start Tomcat I get these error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:123)
    at com.yehang.InitServlet.init(InitServlet.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5516)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Dec 28, 2014 1:36:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /Counter threw load() exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:123)
    at com.yehang.InitServlet.init(InitServlet.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5516)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

When I try to printout the filepath, it is null.

Even After hardcode the filepath like this:

`String filePath = "/Users/yehang/Documents/workspace/Counter/WebContent/recorder.txt";`

This code still doesn't work. It can't read the number from the file.

```
    null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:123)
    at com.yehang.InitServlet.init(InitServlet.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5516)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

The nums which I print out is null. I don't know why. I tried almost same code under another servlet's doGet() method, it works well. The reason must be in the difference between init() and doGet()method. But I don't know. I am newbie in servlet.

Comment: Error is in another servlet it seems 

`Servlet /Counter threw load() exception`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your servlet is not initialized correctly, it seems. Your first call in the overridden `init(ServletConfig)` should be

```
super.init(config);
```

or otherwise you should override `init()`

Comment: Yes It works. However, when I stop the tomcat server. It still didn't call the destroy()method to write the number back to the file.

Comment: I want to invoke the destroy method() to write the number back to the .txt file. But nothing changed in the file after I stop tomcat.

Comment: Again, did you put a breakpoint? Or do you just examine the file contents?

Comment: I add a System.out.println("invoke"); in the destroy() method